# how to upload the app again after app rejection from app store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

My App was rejected by Apple, Now I have fixed the issues and want to upload the updated app but I don't understand that how to upload the new app replace that rejection app.

Comment: increase the build number/version and upload in the same way you did previously

Comment: The process is almost same but you need to increase version/build number before submission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Change "Build Number" of your app and upload again.

[image]

You don't need to remove rejected build from store and may not need to change version no. also. Just upload a new build with new `build no`.

Answer (score 2):

> You only need to fix your code, change build no. and upload it as you upload it first time.

Answer (score 1):

First, login in to [iTunes connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/) and need to do again "Ready to submit binary". Right now your app status should be "Rejected". So you must do that first before uploading through Application loader.

1. In the right pane where the description and screenshots appear,
   scroll down to "Build".
2. Click the red minus sign beside the rejected build to remove it.
3. In your app change your build number.
4. Resubmit the new uploaded version.